# Como fazer os objetos se completarem com a rolagem da página?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Encontrei este [site](https://gardenestudio.com.br/index.php) enquanto navegava na internet, e achei nele uma coisa incrível que não consigo fazer.

Na verdade não sei nem como faço para pesquisar algo sobre. Alguém sabe como faço para ir completando tais objetos de acordo com o *Scroll* do mouse?

Abaixo do título *O Estúdio* tem uma animação nas linhas, elas se completam.

Mais um pouco abaixo tem o lápis e computador que vão se completando também, achei isso incrível.

Alguém tem noção de como faz isso, ou o que eu posso procurar para aprender sobre.

Comment: Basicamente você pega um desenho em svg, "esconde" o path dele e vai revelando de acordo com a porcentagem de scroll do documento: https://css-tricks.com/scroll-drawing/

Comment: É exatamente isso.
Muito obrigado!